# Access value of HTML title attribute as variable in onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access the value of the **HTML title attribute** as a variable for the *onclick* function.

This is an example for my HTML elements:

```
<a title="id:4" onclick="openWin(4)">example</a>
```

This is my **JavaScript** function:

```
function openWin(number)
{
    window.open("http://www.some-example.org/some/example/id:"+number)
}
```

This works but since I have a lot of HTML elements, I'd like to find a way to reference the title value inside the *openWin()* function instead of writing "openWin(someNumber)".
Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: well you would have to access the event sender, so you could use: `openWin(this)` and `el.attr('title')`

Comment: The `title` attribute is not meant to store program data, but human readable descriptions to the current element. [If you need to assign some chunk of data to an HTML element use the `data-*` attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this :

**HTML :**

```
<a title="id:4">example</a>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$(function(){
     $('a[title]').click(function(){
         window.open("http://www.some-example.org/some/example/"+this.title)
     });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    var number = this.title.replace('id:', '');
    window.open("http://www.some-example.org/some/example/id:" + number)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution if you want Number value only from Tittle:

**HTML**

```
<a title="id:4" onclick="openWin(this)">example</a>
```

**JS**

```
function openWin(el)
{
    window.open("http://www.some-example.org/some/example/id:"+el.title.split(':')[1]);


}
```

Here is **live URL**:

http://jsbin.com/eGUCoWU/4/edit

Comment: +1 for `split(':')[1]` even if this answer still uses inline JS event handler;

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
$('a').click(function(){
    titleVar = $(this).attr('title').slice(3,4);
    ... do something with titleVar
 });
```

I might not have got the slice parameters right but, this will grab the title attribute, remove the 'ID:' bit and put the number alone into 'titleVar'. You can then do whatever you wish with titleVar.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  window.open("http://www.some-example.org/some/example/id:"+ $(this).attr('title').split(':')[1]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Inside your event handler function, `this` will be the HTML element on which the event fired.

HTML elements have a `title` property containing the value of the title attribute.

```
onclick="var foo = this.title"
```

You can then do whatever you like with `foo`.